# Why dicom image displayed are inverse colour and lossy for output. (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, tiff, dicom, inverse

Why are the colours inversed when I read a DICOM file? Also, when I am try to stretch and adjust the image output the export files are lossy (TIFF):

```
origImg = dicomread(uigetfile('~/matlab/*.*', 'Select Dicom File')); 

J=imadjust(origImg,stretchlim(origImg),[0 1]);

CExpo = adapthisteq(J,'Distribution','exponential','Alpha',3);

imwrite(CExpo,'finish.tif','Resolution',100);
```

Resource and compare file: https://www.mediafire.com/?2xcwpt4khw3qh06

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's Tiff class inverts uint8 image values when PhotometricInterpretation is 'Separated'. The Tiff specification specifically forbids this, but Matlab does it anyway for reasons unknown to me. That probably answers why your images are inverted. Generally speaking, Tiff images are not a lossy format, so if you believe there is a loss of fidelity, I do not understand how that is happening. (Nor do I know what a dicom image is).